# gitlab-ci - CHROME_BIN still missing in env

Tags: environment-variables, gitlab-ci, karma-jasmine

In my karma config file, I've set `process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();`.

I've installed puppeteer with npm.

```js
  {
    ...
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessCustom'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCustom: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--js-flags=--max-old-space-size=8196',
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

Firstly, dependencies are installed then cached.
Then linting and unit test are run at the same time but only on merge_requests.

```
image: mhart/alpine-node:14

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
  DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "$DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR/client"

services:
  - name: docker:dind
    command: ["--mtu=1300"]

stages:
  - dependencies
  - test

node_modules:
  stage: dependencies
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    policy: push
  when: manual
  script:
    - apk add nss
    - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline --also=dev
  only:
    - merge_requests
  allow_failure: false

unit-test:
  stage: test
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    policy: pull
  script:
    - npm run test:ci
  only:
    - merge_requests
  allow_failure: false

eslint:
  stage: test
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    policy: pull
  script:
    - npm run lint
  only:
    - merge_requests
  allow_failure: false
```

I'm still getting the `Please set env variable CHROME_BIN`.

Could it be the node_modules are not well followed through jobs?
Should I `export CHROME_BIN` instead?

Do not hesitate to suggest things I could write/do better in my ci config file.

Thanks for your help!